# 2005 e280 Mercedes OE parts and auxiliary circuits

Tags: mercedes-benz, traction-control, head-unit

I would like to find out what radio came in my Mercedes E280 sports when it was new and if it has heated seats. It's a 2005.

[The] fellow I got car off took radio out and I think [the buttons] were in it. I've put a stand radio in and can't get seats [warmers], hazard lights, or traction button to work.

[I] think the radio that was taken out has the buttons on it for heated seats, hazard lights, and traction control [because] I've seen in another Mercedes.

Comment: Alright. When you push the seat warmer button (if it exists), does your seat get warm? If there is no such button, that would be a huge clue that it doesn't in fact have heated seats. That's what I would look for...

Comment: It does but fellow I got car off took radio out and I think thy were in it I've put a stand radio in and can't get seats to work or hazard lights or traction button to work

Comment: Are you thinking these are all related to the radio being removed? Or are these all separate problems?

Comment: Yes think the radio that was took out has the buttons on it for heated seats and hazard light button and traction control on the radio I seen in another Mercedes